# npm err! code 1 when installing request module to be used in electron app

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

When trying to install the request using `npm install request`, I get an **npm err! code 1**. I don't understand what this means and I can't find an explanation. What is it and how can I install the request module?

I don't have much experience with the electron. It may be that I may have done something wrong or I'm missing a step.

It is for a web scraper. The `request(URL, function (error, response, html)` will not work without the request module.

Can someone please give me some directions on how to make this work?

Also, I am using a `Windows x64 bit` machine if that helps.

Thanks,

This is what I get when I run the `npm install request`:

```
westhlp@1.0.0 C:\User\myName\Desktop\electnode

`--(empty)

npm Warn westhlp@1.0.0 no description

npm Warn westhlp@1.0.0 no repository field;

npm Err! code 1
```

Comment: What version of node are you running?  My research tells me that running `npm cache clean` might have an effect, but also the node version might too.

Comment: I am running node v6.3.1. Did the npm cache clean and got a whole bunch of 'npm Err!'. I don't know what it means or if that is normal but I tried it.

Comment: That's all the stack trace you got? If not can you post please?

Comment: hi Joaquin Javi, I am no quite sure could you tell me  what to look for....

Comment: @Nb_me What he's asking for is the entire error message that `npm install request` printed out.

Comment: @VadimMacagon oh....ok. Here are the three messages that I received. 'npm warn westhp@1.0.0 no description., 'npm warn westhp@1.0.0 no repository field., and npm err! code 1'

Comment: @Nb_me Nope, that's not it either, I mean literally everything that gets printed out after you run `npm install request`. Edit your question and add the full output there.

Comment: @VadimMacagon Ok.....I added it to the edit post

Comment: @Nb_me Those are just warnings, not show stoppers. I just ran npm install request and it worked fine and I'm on node v4.0.0. You can try deleting the directory node_modules, then run npm install to completely rebuild it.

Comment: @developernator I am trying to find out why I am having trouble installing it in my electron.app.

Comment: I understand that the package is failing and your not providing much diagnosis.  Again, delete the node_modules folder then have node rebuild the structure using npm install. There is a malformed package in there.

Comment: @developernator just simply delete or uninstall?

Comment: you can just remove the directory using rm -R node_module then when you run npm install it will completely rebuild the directory and pull in all the packages again. Don't delete packages.json in your root because that is what node knows to install.

Comment: @developernator I did the 'node rm -R node_module' but it did not remove the node_module folder with content. The folder is still in the project folder. Is this normal or should I "delete" it

Comment: its a normal delete not a node command.... just "rm -R node_modules"  rm is a unix/gitbash command and -R flag mean recursive

Comment: @developernator .... tried it and got a message along the lines of 'rm' is not a recognized command. I am using a windows pc. I know some commands are suppose to work regardless of the machine.

Comment: just delete the directory however you know how to delete a directory

Comment: @developernator ...I had to "npm install rimraf" then "rimraf node_modules" to delete it. Now give me step by step to install so I don't leave out anything.

Comment: Honestly, I think you need to read up more on node... https://www.npmjs.com/

Comment: @developernator ....been doing that and I think my lack of experience is the problem. I can make the project work in node but using request with electron is the trouble... That's my reason for wanting step by step instructions.

Comment: now run 'npm install'

Comment: @developernator ....lol...I knew that part....I ran npm install request also and npm err! code 1" message. does request even work in electron?

Comment: try "npm install --no-bin-links"

Comment: @developernator I did so and also tried npm install request and still the 'npm Err! code 1' message

Comment: Did you get it going?

Comment: @developernator... Yes I will post the solution.

Answer (score 5):

This is the solution to my problem with installing request module. It looks like the request module has to be included inside of the package.json dependencies.

Here is mine.

```
"dependencies": {
"request": "latest",
"cheerio": "latest"
}
```

Once I did this the install went through.

Comment: a simple solution to a ridiculous problem

Comment: Great. Worked for me